# JS global variable and function outside $(document).ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, object-oriented-analysis

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var x = false;
    $('#board_code').keyup(function(e) {
        if(x)
            callFunc();
    })  
})

function callFunc(){
    if(expression==true)
        x=true;
    else
       x=false;
}
```

I know i can just put the def of callFunc inside $(document).ready function, but what is the other way so that i wouldnt use global variable

**UPDATE**:  i forgot to put the **if(x)**, check it again. This is for brace matching in my web-based ide project ^^

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var x = false;
    $('#board_code').keyup(function(e) {
        x = callFunc();
    })  
})

function callFunc(){
  return expresion ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: @fireflieslive, That makes no difference:  `if (x) {var result = callFunc()}`

Comment: There is no benefit to using the inline if, should use `return expresion` over `return expresion ? true : false;` as this adds an if operation without need.  Have a good one, thanks!

Comment: since your expression has to return a true or false.  Whether it ends up being something like `return ("Does this equal this" === "No") ? true : false;` in the end you could of just done `return ("Does this equal this" === "No")`.  The benefit of using inline if is to return non-boolean values.  Examples http://javascript.about.com/od/decisionmaking/a/des10.htm have a good day.

Comment: `since your expression has to return a true or false.` Really? All js expressions return true or false?

Comment: To be used in an inline if yes, if not please provide an example.  I'd love you learn something :)

Comment: `To be used in an inline if yes, if not please provide an example. I'd love you learn something :) – abc123` Sure...function do_stuff() {
  console.log(f());
  console.log(g());
}

function f() {
  return  (1 + 2);
}

function g() {
  return (1 + 2) ? true : false;
}

do_stuff();  output--> 3 true

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JAhp7/ I should of been more clear, if your expression doesn't evaluate to `true or false` you will always hit the `true` if statement of the inline if.  But you are right you you can put anything in the expression, lesson learned. :)

Comment: `I should of been more clear, if your expression doesn't evaluate to true or false you will always hit the true if statement of the inline if.– abc123` Huh?  function g() { return (4 - 4) ? true : false; }

Comment: `0` is `false` any non-zero is `true` for numbers same as C# and Java...  I'm way to sleepy for anymore it is 7am.  Have a good one :)